# Self reference owned types in EF Core JSON columns

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, ef-core-7.0

I want to save these models into a SQL Server database as JSON:

```
public class VersionEntity 
{
    public VersionEntity()
    {
    }

    public VersionItemEntity Items { get; set; }
    public long ProjectId { get; set; }
    public int TenantId { get; set; }
}

public class VersionItemEntity
{
    public List<VersionItemsEntity> VersionItems { get; set; }
}

public class VersionItemsEntity
{
    public VersionItemsEntity()
    {
    }

    public string Key { get; set; }
    public string Label { get; set; }
    public VersionItemsDataEntity Data { get; set; }
    public string Icon { get; set; }
    public List<VersionItemsEntity> Children { get; set; } = new();
}

public class VersionItemsDataEntity
{
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public int? Order { get; set; }
    public DateTime? ReleaseDate { get; set; }
}
```

And the `OnModelCreating` method is :

```
private void VersionModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
{
        modelBuilder.Ignore<VersionItemsDataEntity>();
        modelBuilder.Entity<VersionEntity>().OwnsOne(
          version => version.Items, ownedNavigationBuilder =>
          {
              ownedNavigationBuilder.OwnsMany(
              metadata => metadata.VersionItems, ownedOwnedNavigationBuilder =>
              {
                  ownedOwnedNavigationBuilder.OwnsMany(vi => vi.Children);
                  ownedOwnedNavigationBuilder.OwnsOne(vi => vi.Data);
                  ownedNavigationBuilder.ToJson();
              }
              );
          });
        modelBuilder.Entity<VersionEntity>().Property(o => o.Id).UseIdentityColumn(Back_SoftConsts.InitialValue);
    }
```

When I run `Add-Migration version` in the Package Manager Console, this error appears:

> Unable to determine the owner for the relationship between 'VersionItemsEntity.Children#VersionItemsEntity.Data' and 'VersionItemsDataEntity' as both types have been marked as owned. Either manually configure the ownership, or ignore the corresponding navigations using the [NotMapped] attribute or by using 'EntityTypeBuilder.Ignore' in 'OnModelCreating'. See https://aka.ms/efcore-docs-owned for more information and examples.

Comment: "Owned entities are essentially a part of the owner and cannot exist without it",so Idon't think it's prope to set your entity self owned

Comment: @RuikaiFeng If I remove the line `ownedOwnedNavigationBuilder.OwnsMany(vi => vi.Children);` it is fixed, but the children are not saved